# How to Show System Emoji Keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events

I have task to select Emoji from System Emoji keyboard and show in EditTextView.

Tried below **inputType**:

```
android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
```

Expected to Show System Emoji Keyboard.

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q0J4.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing.  There's no such thing as the "system keyboard".  The keyboard is an app.  Any OEM may install any keyboard app.  There is no single "system keyboard" that is always installed or must be installed.  There is no requirement for any keyboard to display or use emojis.  And there is no API to force display of a particular keyboard layout (even the numbers keyboard is just a hint the keyboard app can use or ignore).  So no, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use EmojiCompat Support Library

add Dependency

```
dependencies {
implementation("androidx.emoji:emoji:28.0.0")}
```

Refer to this [Link](https://www.droidcon.com/2021/10/07/how-to-create-a-basic-emoji-keyboard-in-android-2/)

Comment: Thank you for Reply, But We need to show System UI Keyboard only.